# Use OCL for validation

Tags: jena, ocl, jena-rules

I have a RDF dataset and a some OCL files which discribe the expected shape of the data.

Is there a way verify the data with the OCL files with Jena?

Answer (score 0):

Jena appears to be a complete solution, so extending it is hard. (If it was OSGI plugins, you could install it in Eclipse and exploit complimentary Eclipse functionality.)

If you save your RDF as XML, and have a UML/Ecore metamodel for RDF, then you may use Eclipse OCL tooling in a separate tool.